# Implementing recursive function to find HCF/GCD java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using a simplified version of euclids algorythm to find hcf of two ints. Using a recursive function. Doesn't seem to be working though, its just returning c all the time. Any ideas why its not eventually returning a+b ?

```
 public class Euclid {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Class to find HCF (GCD) of two ints, using recursion

    Euclid r = new Euclid();
    System.out.println(r.hcf(188, 112));
  }

  public int hcf(int a, int b){
   int c = -11;
    if(a == 0 || b == 0){
      return a+b; // base case
    }
    else if (a > b){
      return hcf(a-b, b);
    }
    else if (b > a){
      return hcf(b-a, a);
    }
  return c;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find the greatest common divisor you end up passing in a and b such that `a==b`. You don't handle that case, so `c` is returned.

An easy fix is to just remove the last `if` branch, so that the `a==b` case is handled there.

```
if(a == 0 || b == 0){
   return a+b; // base case
}
else if (a > b){
   return hcf(a-b, b);
}
else { // b > a or a == b
   return hcf(b-a, a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't call non-static methods from `static main`. Second, your algorithm has so many cases that it is hard to tell what you are trying to do. Here's the one-liner I wrote for Euclid's GCD in Python years ago. Let's see if we can translate it to Java.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    return b if not a%b else gcd(b, a%b)
```

Here it is in Java.

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if(!(a % b)) return b;
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

That seems way simpler than whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: Yeah. `int hcf(int a, int b) { return b == 0 ? a : hcf(b, a % b); }` looks even simpler, but that's not the point. And it doesn't matter whether that method is `static` or not - it's called upon class instance.

Comment: @cdshines Methods that do not interact with any instance variables should always be static. Otherwise, each instance must carry it around. It's like extra baggage. To further my point, imagine if main were not static.

Comment: @cdshines If you want to create objects that contain functions that take input, rather than a static function that takes input, you can. The beauty of static functions is that they only exist once in memory.